# Question about moving file associations after creating a boot drive

Tags: windows-7, migration

I recently bought a separate drive to use purely as a boot drive.

I have a bunch of development related applications (SSMS, visual studio, etc) that no longer appear in my start menu and when I try to open their files (a VS project for instance) it's not finding the application.

Is there an easy way to get all of the applications that I had installed on my other drive over to the new drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no, you're going to have to reinstall them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, probably the only way that will work, short of reinstalling everything, is cloning the old drive over to the new one. You will still have to reinstall any new software from then, though.